# Loops python xlsx, repetir acciones

Tags: python, excel, condiciones, bucles, formato-condicional

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Con el código que pegare abajo, cargo mi `.xlsx`. En él tengo columnas y en ellas distintos valores. Agrego una columna más que va a tener un valor especifico para cada fila.

Mi problema es que lo se hacer de forma individual pero no automática y tengo muchísimos registros para calcular:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='Data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Data']

ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:E1"

ws["E1"] = 'Fillrate%'

ws["E2"] = round(((ws['C2'].value)/(float(ws['B2'].value))*100),2)
ws["E3"] = round(((ws['C3'].value)/(float(ws['B3'].value))*100),2)
ws["E4"] = round(((ws['C4'].value)/(float(ws['B4'].value))*100),2)
ws["E5"] = round(((ws['C5'].value)/(float(ws['B5'].value))*100),2)
ws["E6"] = round(((ws['C6'].value)/(float(ws['B6'].value))*100),2)


wb.save("Analized_Data.xlsx")
```

Lo que necesito es que:

```
ws["E2"] = round(((ws['C2'].value)/(float(ws['B2'].value))*100),2)
```

Sea de forma automática para todas las filas, en vez de tener que escribir fila por fila.

Este es mi `xlsx` original:

[image: Original]

Este sería mi resultado hasta el momento:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con un bucle que recorra todas las filas:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='Data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Data']

for row in ws.nrows :
    /* aquí tienes cada fila de la hoja */
      ws["E%s" % row] = round(((ws['C%s' % row].value)/(float(ws['B%s' % row].value))*100),2)

wb.save("Analized_Data.xlsx")
```

> PD: No sé mucho de *Python*, si tengo algún fallo, comentarlo y lo
>   corregiré.

Answer (score 0):

Si se conoce el número de filas puede emplearse una función de ayuda `copyValuesTablas` para copiar tablas, a partir de arreglos creados desde **Python**.

Esto no sólo es útil porque se reutiliza código, sino que permite hacer todas las operaciones habituales en **Python** y luego llamarla para que se inserten las columnas (con sus filas respectivas) que se necesiten.

Por ejemplo, si se quiere insertar los arreglos `C`, `D` y `F` creados desde `Python` a la `Hoja de Excel` cuyas columnas son `C` `D` y `F`, `table` tendría que ser de la forma:

```
table = [[], [], [Datos C], [Datos D], [], [Datos F]]
```

> Algo susceptible de mejorar, pero como indiqué, facilita la indexación de `columnas` y `filas` conocidas, siendo las `filas` iguales en longitud **o diferentes**.

Adicionalmente en la columna `C` y `D` se aprecia valores con `ceros`, entonces una división entre dichos valores (denominador) provocará `indefinido`.

A efecto de evitar lo anterior y no llenarse de fórmulas en **Python** que afecten el flujo de trabajo antes descrito, he visto conveniente insertar la expresión condicional en **Excel**, mediante la [Función SI](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/funci%C3%B3n-si-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) -esta va en inglés en `openpyxl`.

Adicionalmente se agrega a **Excel** la [Función REDONDEAR](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/redondear-funci%C3%B3n-redondear-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c), porque el valor final es obtenido en **Excel** no en **Python**. La anterior función también se coloca en inglés.

Para más detalle sugiero ver: [Nombre en inglés y español de las funciones de Excel](https://excel.facilparami.com/2012/09/nombre-en-espaol-ingles-de-las-funciones-de-excel/)

```
def dividir(i, ws): return '=ROUND(IF($C${0}=0,0,$C${0}/$B${0})*100,2)'.format(i)
```

Aquí la implementación creando los datos y el libro desde el mismo `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import random               # para generar valores
random.seed( 20190317 )     # aleatorios con una semilla

#  -----------------------------------------
#  FUNCION DE AYUDA
#  -----------------------------------------
#  Para copiar tablas N x M
#  si quieres alguna posición especifica
#  agregar listas vacias
#  no optimo quizas, pero reutilizas codigo
#  ----------------------------------------
#  USO:
#  Si se quiere copiar las columnas C, D y F:
#  table tendria que tener la siguiente forma:
#  [[], [], [Datos C], [Datos D], [], [Datos F]]
#  ----------------------------------------
def copyValuesTablas(table, sheet):  
    for nCol, lista in enumerate(table):
        for nRow, valor in enumerate(lista):
            sheet.cell(column=nCol+1, row=nRow+1, value=valor)
            #print(nCol + 1, nRow + 1, valor)  #control


# -----------------------------------------
# DATOS INICIALES
# -----------------------------------------

# numero de filas que tendra el proyecto
nFilas=20

# valores en las columnas
A=["auto{0}".format(i) for i in range(nFilas)]
B=[random.randint(1,1230) for i in range(nFilas)]
C=[random.randint(1,130) for i in range(nFilas)]
D=[random.random()*100 for i in range(nFilas)]

# nombre de cabeceras
A.insert(0,"AUTOS")
B.insert(0,"Ad Oportunidad")
C.insert(0,"Ad impresion")
D.insert(0,"gtrd")

# tabla
tabla = [A, B, C, D]
# -----------------------------------------


#  ----------------------------------------
#  Configuracion del Entorno de Trabajo
#  ----------------------------------------
libroDestino = 'Analized_Data.xlsx'
# creamos un archivo que al final se salvará
miLibro = Workbook()

#  Se renombra Sheet por 'Data'
miLibro.active.title = 'Data'
ws = miLibro['Data']

# creación de los datos
copyValuesTablas(tabla, ws)
#  ----------------------------------------



#  ----------------------------------------
#  Se realizan los calculos
#  en este caso se inserta
#  una formula de excel en la columna E
#  a partir de la segunda fila
#  ----------------------------------------
def dividir(i, ws): return '=ROUND(IF($C${0}=0,0,$C${0}/$B${0})*100,2)'.format(i)

startRow = 2 # los calculos empiezan en la segunda fila
E = [ dividir(i, ws) for i in range(startRow, nFilas+startRow ) ]
E.insert(0, "Fillrate%") # cabecera de E


# se crea una tabla nueva
# dejando en blanco
# las columnas A,B,C y D
x = [[]] * len(tabla)
x.insert(len(tabla) + 1, E)

# creación de los datos
copyValuesTablas(x, ws)
#  ----------------------------------------


#  ----------------------------------------
# Se guarda
miLibro.save(libroDestino)
#  ----------------------------------------
```

El resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]